# Multiple annotations at same coordinate

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

Actually I am working in `MKMapview`. according to coordinate, different annotation is generated, in the case of multiple annotation at same coordinate, it only show first and last data.I am unable to show the middle data of annotation. so my questions is 
how to show the more than two annotation of same coordinate in `MKMapview`?

Using below code i am able to show the all the data at any same coordinate, now i have another problem, that is confusion between two or more same coordinate. It means when i have two or more that two point having same coordinate, it confuse. If you have any idea plz share with us.
.........

```
int nextAnnotationToSelect = (lastAnnotationSelected + 1)

% mapView.annotations.count;

id<MKAnnotation> nextAnnotation =[mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:nextAnnotationToSelect];

[mapView selectAnnotation:nextAnnotation animated:YES];

lastAnnotationSelected = nextAnnotationToSelect;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method to display multiple annotations in same coordinate:

http://blog.stormid.com/2013/01/handling-annotation-pins-on-the-same-coordinate/

Comment: thanks for ur response, i tried but i was unable to integrate given sample code into my project. I am searching for simple code which fulfil my requirement.

Answer (score -2):

```
Mulitple Annotation on the single field. Here is description 
public class Role
{
  [Display(Name="First Name")]
  [Required]
  [Length=30(Minlength=2)]
  [ErrorMessage="Value required"]
  public string Fname{get;set;}

 [Display(Name="Last Name")]
 [Required]
 [Length=30 (Minlength=2)]
 [ErrorMessage="Last name invalid"]

}
```